# Getting org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR adding root node to document

Tags: java, xml, xerces, xalan

I'm trying to create a simple XML document and am receiving the above error when adding the root element to the document.  I only have the one root element (the first element created for the document) and the error throws on the first append_child() call.  Here is the code leading up to where the error throws (on the securityDoc.appendChild(securityDoc) call):

```
 public Document CreateSecurityHeader() throws ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document securityDoc = builder.newDocument();

    try {
        Element securityRoot = securityDoc.createElementNS("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "wsse:Security");            
        securityRoot.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        securityRoot.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
        securityRoot.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:env", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
        securityRoot.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:wss","http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
        securityRoot.setAttribute("env:mustUnderstand", "1");            
        securityDoc.appendChild(securityDoc);
```

As this is the only Element in that document at this point, how am I getting the this error?  I did have to pull in the xalan and xerces library as dependencies for this project for something else, could there be an incompatibility here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops. You append `securityDoc` to `securityDoc`.

```
securityDoc.appendChild(securityDoc);
```

I'm sure you mean this:

```
securityDoc.appendChild(securityRoot);
```

I only noticed this myself by stepping through the validation code and when it was using the node lookup tables to check whether the proposed tree structure is legal I saw that what you were appending was `DOCUMENT_NODE`, which is not legal to append to a `DOCUMENT_NODE`.

Comment: Ah, yup, that was it.  I looked that over at least 30 times and missed that every time.  Thanks!

Comment: @stu33 please accept this answer if it solved your problem, thanks.